# Mockito: Boolean cannot be returned by findById() findById() should return Optional

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, option-type

I've the following test case I am testing and this line is causing an exception:

> **when(actorService.actorExists(actorId)).thenReturn(true)**
>
> Boolean cannot be returned by findById() findById() should return
> Optional

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
    public class MovieServiceTest {
    
        @Mock
        private MovieRepository movieRepository;
    
        @Mock
        ActorRepository creativesRepository;
    
        @InjectMocks
        private MovieService movieService;
    
        @InjectMocks
        private ActorService actorService;
    
        @BeforeEach
        public void setUp() {
            MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);
        }     
       @Test
            public void testDeleteActorNotInMovie() throws CreativesDeletionException, CreativesNotFoundException {
                // Mock the dependencies
                Long actorId = 1L;
                Actor actor = new Actor();
                actor.setId(actorId);
                when(creativesRepository.findById(actorId)).thenReturn(Optional.of(actor));
        
                when(actorService.actorExists(actorId)).thenReturn(true);
        }
    }
```

The class I am testing

```
    @Service
    public class ActorService extends CreativesServiceImpl<Actor, ActorRepository> {
    
        public Optional<Actor> findById(Long id){
            return creativesRepository.findById(id);
        }
    
        public boolean actorExists(Long actorId) {
            Optional<Actor> actorOpt = creativesRepository.findById(actorId);
    
            return actorOpt.isPresent();
        }
}
```

I tried to see similar posts in stackoverflow but I still couldn't find the root problem and resolution to my issue.

Comment: `ActorService` isn't a mock so `when(actorService.actorExists(actorId)).thenReturn(true);` won't work. You need to invoke the method and assert the result. Also doing what you do with an optional is actually pretty bad, instead use the `existsById` method from the `CreativesREpository` (I'm assuming a Spring Data repostiroy in this case).

Comment: Which method are you refering by "invoke the method" ?

Comment: The long and short of the problem: `#when` expects an `Optional<T>` to compare that present `T` to your `#thenReturn`. It's a convenience method for testing optional values, but you don't have an `Optional<T>`, you have a `boolean`. The "invoked method" spoken of earlier is your `#actorExists`.

Comment: I explicitly stated which method it is. `actorService.actorExists` you should just invoke it and not register mockito behavior on it. As it is the class you want to test.